# AZURE modify JWT token fields

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-web-app-service

We have two applications: `Application A` and `Application B`

We are creating token by calling `https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/v2.0/token` endpoint with credentials from `Application B` and `scope` value for `Application A`.

We want to add extra field into JWT token what we are getting from these request, it should have hardcoded value.

In future we will want to add `Application C` and use the same logic.

Example:
In user flow we can have emails, so lets try we want to add emails field into JWT but for applications

We can't use Azure functions

I tried to create MappingPolicy with custom data, but I can't see it, tried to create ClaimsExtensions but I belive it's for users only

So we need to add custom hardcoded value assigned to `Application B` and be able to see it in JWT body after getting token for `Application A`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by customizing the claims issued in the JWT token for your enterprise applications.

To add a custom hardcoded value to the JWT token, you can follow these steps:

1. Open the Azure portal and navigate to the Enterprise Applications
   experience for Application A and B.
2. Select the Single sign-on blade in the left-hand menu and open the Attributes & Claims section.
3. Click on Add Claim and enter the name of the claim you want to add
   (in this case, "emails").
4. Set the Value field to the hardcoded value
   you want to assign to Application A and B.
5. Save the changes.

After following these steps, the custom claim with the hardcoded value will be added to the JWT token for Application A and B. You can repeat these steps for Application C as well.

Please note that if you are not able to see the custom claim in the JWT token, it may be because the claim is not included in the token by default. In this case, you can add the claim to the token by editing your application manifest to request it